# Conditional branch (BNE) always registers as equal. Is the flag not getting set?

Tags: assembly, arm

I am writing a simple program for my class and everything appears to be working except for the conditional branch (BNE). I either have an issue in my SUBS or BNE line.

```
        LDR R4, =input @ input between 1 and 6
        LDR R5, =secret @ a "secret" number(4) set in the .data section
        SUBS R7, R5, R4 @ R7=R5-R4 and set flags
        BNE else @Branch if zero flag is not set
```

I've tried using CMP instead of SUBS, but encountered the same issue

My full code:

```
.data
.balign 4
intro: .asciz "Guess the number (1-6):  "

.balign 4
win: .asciz "You win!\n"

.balign 4
lose: .asciz "Wrong!\n"

.balign 4
input: .word #0

.balign 4
secret: .word #4

.text
.global _start
_start:
        MOV R7, #4
        MOV R0, #1
        MOV R2, #24
        LDR R1, =intro
        SWI 0

        MOV R7, #3
        MOV R0, #0
        MOV R2, #1
        LDR R1, =input
        SWI 0

        BAL if
if:
        LDR R4, =input
        LDR R5, =secret
        SUBS R7, R5, R4
        BNE else

        MOV R7, #4
        MOV R0, #1
        MOV R2, #12
        LDR R1, =win
        SWI 0

        BAL end
else:
        MOV R7, #4
        MOV R0, #1
        MOV R2, #12
        LDR R1, =lose
        SWI 0
end:
        MOV R7, #1
        SWI 0
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT:
I modified my code to:

```
LDR R4, =input
LDR R1, [R4]
LDR R5, =secret
LDR R2, [R5]
SUBS R3, R1, R2
```

But the BNE still isn't working. I ran dbg and these are the registers right before the SUBS:

```
r0    0x1      1  
r1    0x34     52 @SHOULD be "input", I entered 4
r2    0x4      4  @ the "secret" number
r3    0x0      0
r4    0x20130  131376  @the address of input
r5    0x20134  131380  @the address of secret
r6    0x0
r7    0x3
r8    0x0
r9    0x0
r10   0x0
r11   0x0
r12   0x0
sp    0x7efff790  0x7efff790
lr    0x0       0
pc    0x100b0   0x100b0 <if+16>
cpsr  0x10      16
```

Is the error in my input? I don't see anything wrong with it, but I'm not experienced with assembly.

```
MOV R7, #3
MOV R0, #0
MOV R2, #1
LDR R1, =input
SWI 0
```

Thanks again!

Comment: The `=` operator loads the address, not the value. Those two addresses will never match. You need to load from memory.

Comment: 0x34 is the ASCII code for the character `'4'`, so you're doing it right but you have your secret stored as an integer, not a character.

Comment: @Jester Thank you! I edited my post with the changes, but I'm still having trouble with "input" being stored correctly. I was able to verify that "secret" is being stored into the register correctly.

Comment: Why don't you just compare against an immediate `'4'` (with the quotes), instead of loading it from memory?  Either way, the problem is integers vs. ASCII codes.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, so I need to cast "input" to an int? That makes sense.

Comment: No, it's not like a C cast.  It's like the trivial one-digit case of atoi().  (Or avoid that by storing the character code `'4'` (0x34) instead of the integer `4`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you! It's working (almost) perfectly now!